# Ionic HttpClient get Request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httprequest

I have a Restful API, when make a get HttpRequest to this API from postman it works like a charm, but when i implenmented it on Ionic i got this error :

```
ERROR Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", error: error } vendor.js:1703:5
defaultErrorLogger http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1703:5
ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1764:9
IonicErrorHandler.prototype.handleError http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:120941:9
next http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5729:136
EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn< http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4576:36
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:32170:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:32117:17
Subscriber.prototype._next http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:32057:9
Subscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:32021:13
Subject.prototype.next http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:39726:17
EventEmitter.prototype.emit http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4556:24
onHandleError/< http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5004:57
F</l</t.prototype.invoke http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14974
F</c</r.prototype.run http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10124
NgZone.prototype.runOutsideAngular http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4930:54
onHandleError http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5004:13
F</l</t.prototype.handleError http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15054
F</c</r.prototype.runTask http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10869
F</h</e.invokeTask http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16787
p http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27646
v http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893
```

[image]

I made a provider named AuthServiceProvider Here's the Provider code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
let apiUrl = "http://pfeapi/api/v1/"
/*
Generated class for the AuthServiceProvider provider. 

See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
}


public getData(type): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(apiUrl + type);


}

}
```

And a Login function named Login:

```
Login(){
this.data = this.authServiceProvider.getData("users");
this.data.subscribe(data => {
//Username and Password verification code here
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CORS issue. You're serving the app on chrome, right?

Run the following command on `Win+R`

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Serve the app on this browser and try performing the `GET` operation. It will work perfectly.

You can read more on CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You face it only while testing on browser. It will not trouble you when it is run on the device.

Comment: I tried that it still doesnt work :x tried to disable web security on firefox same error

Comment: Actually it WORKS !! Thanks maan

Comment: I tries on Mobile with Ionic DevApp but its not working x(((

Comment: Try USB-debugging the app on your mobile and read through its console. You might find the issue now.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49603652/9321880) answer of mine.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that that URL is not prepared correctly.  I can see it in the code as well `let apiUrl = "http://pfeapi/api/v1/"` you first need to move this line into the class. Secondly, the URL is not formatted correctly.  It should be like this :

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthServiceProvider {
    // The apiUrl below needs reformatting. This is, in any case, a wrong URL
    let apiUrl = "http://pfeapi/api/v1/";
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
    }


    public getData(type): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get(apiUrl + type);


    }

    }
```

Comment: Its works if i go directly on this link and if i make the get request using postman

Comment: Yes its corect look at @Akash answer its working now